# Query multiple Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am needing to create a gallery containing entries from two different models/tables, let's say "video" and "image". What is the best way to handle this? I would like to keep them in different tables, but retrieve them together (the most recent 50 images and videos, for example). Single Table Inheritance doesn't seem to fit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymorphism is your friend.

```
class Video
  belongs_to :viewable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Image
  belongs_to :viewable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Gallery
  has_many :media, :as => :viewable
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have been able to figure is to have a table of all the displays with polymorphic references to the other tables.

```
class Gallery
  has_many :displays
end

class Display
  belongs_to :gallery
  belongs_to :derived_display, :polymorphic => true
end

class Video
  has_one :display, :as => :derived_display
end
```